# ROS2 Package using both C++ and Python

Tags: c++, colcon, build, cmake, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I configure a ROS2 package that contains both C++ and python code for installation? I am aware of a [previous question here](https://answers.ros.org/question/298740/ros2-c-and-python-in-same-package-is-it-possible/), but the answer does not provide an example. I tried following the [tutorial here](https://github.com/bponsler/ros2-support/blob/master/tutorials/creating-a-mixed-cpp-and-python-package.md), but I get `No executable found` when trying to run my python script with `ros2 run` (the C++ executables run without issue).

How do I configure my CMakeLists.txt to install python scripts so that `ros2 run` can find them?

Edit: I have also tried the [call to `install(FILES <script.py> DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})` used here](https://github.com/Kukanani/picky_robot/blob/9a3697301ae117c5cc4f41fbbee5e6c25a1631fe/CMakeLists.txt#L84) to no avail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309391/ros2-package-using-both-c++-and-python/) by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-11-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-12-03**:
Hi,

have you tried adding launch.py in CMakelist.txt and launch the nodes  pass the test.
I have migrated .test files from ros1 to launch.py in ros2 but not able to add it in CMakelist.txt.
With ros1, we can do with rostest.

Thanks,
Poonam

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-12-05**:
@poonam1120 I've already asked you to not use answers to ask questions. Please use comments.

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-12-06**:
@william,
My apologies.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-12-06**:
No worries, just try to use comments unless it's actually an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works for me in bouncy:

```
install(PROGRAMS scripts/demo.py DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

https://github.com/lucasw/imgui_ros/blob/bouncy/imgui_ros/CMakeLists.txt#L96

PROGRAMS sets the installed file permissions to be executable- but the file has to *already* be executable, e.g. `chmod a+x my_node.py`.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-28**:
This works, but only after clearing the `build` and `install` directories, and does not work with the `--symlink-install` option. Is it possible to get it to play nice with `--symlink-install`?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-28**:
I'll take a look at symlink install- I didn't realize until looking it up now that it was the new approach to the ros1 'devel' build directory.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-29**:
I ran symlink-install with a clean workspace (also used with `--base-paths` to use the same src directory as I already set up without making a symlink) and in install/imgui_ros/lib/imgui_ros there is a symlink to demo.py, it works:

```
source install/setup.bash
ros2 run imgui_ros demo.py
```

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-29**:
This still doesn't work for me. The symlink to the script is being created in the install folder, but `ros2 run` is not finding it. I installed bouncy from binaries, so if you did an install from source, perhaps this was bug that was fixed?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-29**:
I've been using the bouncy binaries.

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-29**:
Well, then I'm at a loss as to why this doesn't work.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-30**:
Can you makie a minimal example and put it on github, just a cpp and py node that print something?

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-30**:
See [here](https://github.com/JacobJBeck/ros2_cpp_py_package).

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-11-30**:
Setting the script as executable does the trick! Presumably colcon copies the file and sets it as executable normally, but using `--symlink-install` preserves the existing permissions. Thanks for your help!